# Laravel - Trying to get property 'token' of non-object", exception: "ErrorException"

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I am using Angular-7 as frontend and Laravel-5.8 as backend for a web application.

ApiController.php

```
 public function login(Request $request)
 {
   $request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|string|email',
    'password' => 'required|string',
    'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    $credentials['active'] = 1;
    $credentials['deleted_at'] = null;
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
    return response()->json([
      'message' => 'Unauthorized'
    ], 401);

    $user = $request->user();
    $res = User::with('roles')->find($user->id);
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    if ($request->remember_me)
    $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(13);
    $token->save();
    return response()->json([
      'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
      'token_type' => 'Bearer',
      'expires_at' => Carbon::parse($tokenResult->token->expires_at)->toDateTimeString(),
            'user' => response()->json($res)->original
        ]);
    }
```

From the Angular frontend, when I click on submit on the Login Page, it suppose to redirect to home page. But I got this error:

> {message: "Trying to get property 'token' of non-object", exception: "ErrorException", file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\clientportal-app\backend\app\Http\Controllers\ApiController.php", line: 212, trace: Array(35)}

When I checked line 212 from Laravel ApiController from the code above, this is what I have:

> $token = $tokenResult->token;

How do I resolve it?

Comment: this is not related to angular this error is on your server side

Comment: How do I resolve it from the server side?

Comment: pls copy the code on the ApiController line 212, mostly the error is in the way you're accessing the token value

Comment: Are you using Laravel Passport?

Comment: @Dino Numić - Yes

Comment: @ Ali Al Amine  -  This is line 212:    $token = $tokenResult->token;   Then the ApiController.php   is already in the post

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Passport requires following configuration.
User model needs to use the `HasApiTokens` trait.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;
}
```

Passport routes need to added to the `boot()` method of `AuthServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();
    }
```

And finally change the api driver to passport in `auth` config file.

```
'api' => [
      'driver' => 'passport',
      'provider' => 'users',
]
```

You need to migrate Passport tables

```
php artisan migrate
```

and generate encryption keys

```
php artisan passport:install
```

Clear cache with

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and serve your app

```
php artisan serve
```